# Restore repository to a previous GIT commit

Tags: git

I would like to "roll back" a Git repository to a previous commit.

- I have committed many times (30?) since the [PREVIOUS COMMIT].
- I do NOT want to retain the history or changes of these later commits. I want to delete everything after the [PREVIOUS COMMIT].

Can someone please explain the process for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You would use `git reset --hard [PREVIOUS COMMIT]`  This resets the repository to the commit dropping all changes.

https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reset.html